# Edit CSS class when declaring the div

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to edit a CSS class (thats in an external file) when inputting it into your html/whatever?
I am trying to use the same class twice but I want a space between them

Example:

```
.content {
  width: 65%;
  padding: 2% 2% 2% 2%;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: gold;
  line-height: 200%;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

And then in the html

```
<div class="content">
     blah blah blah
</div>
<div class="content" margin-top: 5px;>
     blee blee blee
</div>
```

Comment: `<div class="content" margin-top: 5px;>` should be `<div class="content" style="margin-top: 5px;">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better form to not have css strewn about but you can do this:

```
<div class="content" style="margin-top: 5px;">
     blee blee blee
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can add an id or just another class

```
<div class="content top-margin">
     blee blee blee
</div>
```

And add one class to the css:

```
.top-margin {
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, the first one is what I was looking for. Thank you so much, I face palmed a bit. One question though, are you saying that I can add a class to a class in css? or did you mean to write .content top-margin?

Comment: No, a div can have multiple classes. So you can add top-margin to anything you want to add margin-top: 5px to.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do, but if I understand correctly you want the second  to have a 5px margin-top. 
you can simply do

```
<div class="content" style="margin-top: 5px;"> blee blee blee </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_Started/Cascading_and_inheritance

There's different levels of CSS and the inline CSS `style="margin-top: 5px;"` overwrites external CSS.

So yes, what you're doing is almost correct; just do a bit more research.

Comment: Thanks, I knew I was close. I never can think of the right way to word coding questions.